# What is the name of this space-based horror film?

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror, science-fiction

I saw a film when I was very young, so my memory is a little hazy. The film is from the 80’s or maybe the very early 90’s.

The film set aboard a spaceship and there is something possessing the crew (possibly the devil...)

There is a female android with short hair which kind of acts like the ships computer. To my memory she is only ever located in one room.

At one point when being approached by a possessed crew member she says:

> Get away from me fu**er.

(that line always stuck with me for some reason)

I think the crew of the ship pick up the demon or devil when visiting another abandoned ship. When they are looking around in one of the cabins there is a troll doll.

At the very end there are just two crew members left, one of them being possessed. The other crew member either blows up the ship or flys it into a black hole.

If anyone has any ideas what this film could be I’d love to know what it is as its been bugging me for a long time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like [Dark Side of the Moon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099364/combined) from 1990.

> "The Dark Side of The Moon" takes place in 2022 as **the crew of a spaceship is forced to land on the entitled dark side of the moon because of an obscure system failure. Unexpectedly a decades-old NASA shuttle, which went missing in action, appears and drifts towards them. They board the space-wreck** in hope of finding some supplies or oxygen stored, not knowing that the ship originally vanished in the spooky Bermuda Triangle! And neither is any of them aware of the fact that **Satan itself is waiting on the ship, quite eager to bloodily snatch the souls of all crew members** as part of a scheme by which Satan may rightfully return to Heaven...

The ship's computer is a short-haired female robot—named Lesli—who indeed [says at some point](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099364/quotes):

> Get away from me, you motherf#@%er!

Comment: +1: This is most likely the film, but outside of the female robot, a lot of what the original poster describes sounds like [*Event Horizon* (1997)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVlnER8SxfQ).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, there are many movies with similar plots (*Supernova* and *Dracula 3000* also come to mind)

Comment: Classic plot: Don’t explore new things! Because here is your predecessor! Rummage through their stuff and find… SATAN! *yawn*

Comment: Yes, Its Dark Side of the Moon! I was only young when I watched it so some points were a little vague. Just watched the YouTube clip and everything came flooding back to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure it doesn’t have a short-haired female robot, but a lot of what’s described sounds like [*Event Horizon*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119081/?ref_=ttmd_md_nm) from 1997:

> A rescue crew investigates a spaceship that disappeared into a black
>   hole and has now returned...with someone or something new on-board.